# What counts as "completing" a Trials of Osiris ticket?

Tags: destiny

For the Trials of Osiris bounty [Ticket to Fight](http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Ticket_to_Fight), what does it mean to "complete a ticket"?  Does it require winning 9 matches, or does it involve winning less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You complete a ticket by either winning 9 games, or losing 3 games - which ever comes first. If you buy all of the boons, these are included - so you can get one win for free (assuming you win your first game), and one loss doesn't count (so you will need to lose 4 games).